# how to use DecoratingStringHashMapper with kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

With spring data keyvalue example have a code below:

```
private final HashMapper<Post, String, String> postMapper =
   new DecoratingStringHashMapper<Post>(
        new JacksonHashMapper<Post>(Post.class));
```

I use kotlin online tool, it convert to :

```
private val postMapper = DecoratingStringHashMapper<Post>(
JacksonHashMapper<Post>(Post::class.java))
```

but idea ide tell's me that:

> Error:(28, 5) Kotlin: Type mismatch: inferred type is
>   JacksonHashMapper but HashMapper! was expected

how to do with that?

Comment: DecoratingStringHashMapper is package in org.springframework.data.redis.hash.DecoratingStringHashMapper

Comment: I tried your code myself and it works fine. Maybe make sure your version of Kotlin and its compiler is up to date. Also it seems as if JacksonHashMapper has been deprecated.

Comment: yet, it upgrade to Jackson2HashMapper,and kotlin look's like didn't need Typed, and i try use 
  private val postMapper = DecoratingStringHashMapper(Jackson2HashMapper(true)),it's just fine. and i still coding full example to try. I am sure my kotlin and its compiler is up to date.

Comment: sorry. its very bad luck.the example's pojo's property type all a string type, but my model have much Long property, i dont want to continue to do this, i get up this way.

Answer (score 0):

good news,with kotlin didn't need the typed,just use that like this:

```
  private val postMapper = 
       DecoratingStringHashMapper(Jackson2HashMapper(true))
```

hope its help!